# In Cocoa how to handle slider change in real time?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Very noob question, I know, but I didn't manage to handle real-time slider move action, the only result I've got is firing certain action once mouseup event happened. But what should I do if I want, for example, a label text change together with slider when I move it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select the slider in the xib file.  Then select the attributes inspector tab.  In the state section, check the box for "continuous" to make the slider update in real-time.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Enable continuous updates for the `NSSlider` in Interface Buider and implement the following delegate:

```
- (IBAction)sliderChanged:(id)sender {
}
```